# How to customize QFileDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a single `QFileDialog` window:

I wonder if there is a way to customize it so instead of "real" folders and files it would list some "arbitrary" "custom" items passed to it as arguments (just like with `QComboBox` or `QListWidget` Item1, Item2, Item3 and etc). Essentially I would like `QFileDialog` to display a list of the predefined files and folders.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

mainWindow=QtGui.QWidget()
openFileDialog=QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(mainWindow, 'Open file', '/mnt')

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This is very old, but still, it seems related to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568065/how-to-add-custom-items-to-qfiledialog