# How to add custom items to QFileDialog?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am using non-native `QFileDialog` (for choosing directory path) and I need to add some custom drives. I don't even need to display any content inside of these drives for now, I just need to display these drives on the top level (and preferably with my icon) and output some special string in the result when user selects it.

[image]

What is the easiest way to implement this?

I have read in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel) that proxy model can be used for that, but I don't understand how to implement such model, all examples show only filtering and sorting of the already available items.

Comment: So you want to add fake drives? Unfortunately out of the box `QFileDialog` doesn't offer this behaviour. An option would be to build your own dialog and use a custom `QFileSystemModel`

Comment: Yes. Are sure that it doesn't support this? Docs say that proxy model can be used "if you want to modify the underlying model; for example, to add columns, filter data or **add drives**."

Comment: I can see how to filter rows, but to add rows I'm not sure, sorry

Comment: Maybe try editing the underlying file system model.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add additional drives to the side bar on the left side of the file dialog?

The function you are looking for is `QFileDialog::setSidebarUrls`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;

    QWidget widget;
    QHBoxLayout layout(&widget);

    QPushButton open("open");
    layout.addWidget(&open);

    QObject::connect(&open, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]()
        {
            QFileDialog dialog;
            dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

            QList<QUrl> drives;
            drives << QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir("D:").absolutePath());
            drives << QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir("E:").absolutePath());
            drives << QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir("foobar").absolutePath());
            dialog.setSidebarUrls(drives);

            dialog.exec();
        });

    window.setCentralWidget(&widget);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The result of this is shown below:

[image]

If, however, the drives you've added don't exist / aren't accessible, then they will be shown greyed out.

Comment: oh, I guess it's also a good option, however I actually wanted to add it at the top level of directory hierarchy where all Windows drives are displayed (a.k.a. "My Computer"). It's Windows-only app. Added screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 3):

## General Information

You are right that you need to set a proxy model.
Basically your task is to add a row with a `QAbstractProxyModel`. This is quite a bit more difficult than removing rows.

If we look at the source code of [`QFileDialog::setProxyModel`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp#n3034), we find this:

```
proxyModel->setParent(this);
d->proxyModel = proxyModel;
proxyModel->setSourceModel(d->model);
```

From this we know that `QFileDialog`has an internal model which is automatically set as the source of the proxy model. Looking in the [private header](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog_p.h#n232), we find that the source model's type is `QFileSystemModel`. We can therefore expect that our proxy model needs to be able to supply the same roles as the source model. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#Roles-enum) has a list of them: `FileIconRole`, `FileNameRole`, `FilePathRole`, `FilePermissionRole`.

To make matters worse, `QFileDialog` [sometimes calls `proxyModel.mapToSource()` and `proxyModel.mapFromSource()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog_p.h#n342) to access the source index. Because we want to add a row, our new indexes have no corresponding source index (in the source model). This means we have to write our own implementation of `mapToSource` and `mapFromSource`.

## Implementation

I would suggest starting from a [`QIdentityProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html) because you can use the available methods for all indexes you just pass to the source model.

I don't know exactly how many methods you need to re-implement and how often you can just use the ones provided by `QIdentityProxyModel`. Start with the easy stuff:

```
int MyDriveProxyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const {
    if (parent.isValid()) {
        return QIdentityProxyModel::rowCount(parent);
    } else {
        return QIdentityProxyModel::rowCount(parent) + 1;
    }
}
```

and then re-implement the two mapping methods:

```
QModelIndex MyDriveProxyModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const {
    if (this_index_belongs_to_the_added_row) { // there are many ways for this
        return this->createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), /* some_data */);
    }
    return QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(proxyIndex);
}

QModelIndex MyDriveProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const {
    ...
}
```

Once this works, you need to do implement at least `QAbstractItemModel::data` and `QAbstractItemModel::flags` in a similar manner.

## Conclusion

It should be doable but is quite a bit of work where it's very easy to make mistakes. What Qt really seems to need is a way to combine multiple models into one, but I haven't seen such a class yet and therefore you'll have to do this the hard way.